# How to block spamming SMS

Tags: motorola-moto-g, 8.0-oreo, sms-blocking

I am using a `MOTO-G6` and it runs on `Android-8.0.0`. the default SMS app is Google-Messages.

I am getting tons of annoying spam SMS from contacts with no numbers.
It just shows a name for example:

```
VKHLTCHK
HPFAMDOC
HPYESBNK
...
...
```

I can block these contacts, But I still do receive sms from these over and over again.

Has anyone have this kind of problem. How do you solve this? I am  willing to buy a paid app if it exists.

Comment: Does the content of the spam SMS varies or remains more or less same? If there are certain keywords which exist in all of those messages, you can setup a filter  in MacroDroid app to detect such spam messages and remove the notification immediately before you are notified. It doesn't remove the sms though, so it would be visible when you open your SMS app.

Comment: Please enable spam protection in messages app. Open messages, settings, advanced, spam protection and enable it. And when a spam message arrives, report it. Such messages won't show further. If you can't see such settings, update messages app to the latest.

Comment: @Firelord Nope. The content is always same.

Comment: @RahulGopi : I am talking about SMS app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en it does not have spam protection feature

Comment: I am also using the same messages(version 4.0.054) app on my moto x4(android pie). I think the features are OS version independent, that means features are same on every android versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your stock SMS app with Textra (free). It has a simple & effective blacklist feature. Just long press on the offending text message, tap Blacklist, done.